# drawingView in front of GridView - Android

Tags: java, android, gridview, drawing

I am building an app that when a person drags their finger across the screen a dot follows their finger. I need the dot to change color as it moves across areas of the screen.

I am thinking of trying to get a `GridView` behind the `drawingView`.
When your finger passes along the items in the GridView, the dot (created in the drawingView) follows your finger and changes color as it passes through the items.

So far I have a dot that follows your finger across the screen. I now need to get it changing colors as it moves over different parts. When I try to put a test GridView behind the drawingView the GridView shows up in front. I've tried `.bringToFront();` in Java and `FrameLayout` in XML but to no avail.

What I would like it to be:

Image of GridView (it would be invisible, in the app)

[image]

Image of the dot following finger as it moves along the grid:

[image]

*(Ideally what looks like clicking in the gif should be dragging)*

Here is my **MainActivity.java** code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

drawingView dview;
GridView gridview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dview = new drawingView(this);

    setContentView(dview);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity1);
    dview.bringToFront();

    final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gridview.setVisibility(GridView.VISIBLE);

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) { 

            ImageView tv = (ImageView) gridview.getChildAt(position);
            tv.setImageResource(R.drawable.touch); //
            tv.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

        }
    });
}
```

My **drawingView.java** file:

```
public class drawingView extends View implements OnTouchListener {

static int x, y, r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
final static int radius = 30;
Paint big;
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

public drawingView(Context context) {

    // for the dot that follows your finger
    big = new Paint();
    big.setAntiAlias(true);
    big.setARGB(100, 255, 255, 255);
    setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);

    setFocusable(true);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);

}

@Override
// creating dot that follows your finger
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, big);
    for (Point p : points) {
        canvas.drawCircle(p.x, p.y, 10, small);
    }
    invalidate();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    big.setARGB(255, 113, 113, 113);

    x = (int) event.getX() - (radius / 2);
    y = (int) event.getY() - (radius / 2);
    randColor();

    int eventaction = event.getAction();
    switch (eventaction) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        big.setARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
        invalidate();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

public void randColor() {
    r = 255;
    g = 0;
    b = 0;
}

}
```

And finally my **ImageAdapter**:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;

}

public Integer[] mThumbIds = {R.drawable.images...};
}
```

I know from another question that I asked before that it is not possible to stack views while interacting with all of them. However I know there must be a way to achieve what I need, even if it's not the way I'm doing it. If anyone knows a way to help with my code or even knows an alternative method it would be great.

**EDIT**

my **activity_activity1.xml** layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".Activity1" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnWidth="33dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:height="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:color="#00000000" >
</GridView>


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".Activity1" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="33dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:height="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:color="#00000000" >
</GridView>
<RelativeLayoutandroid:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:id="@+id/drawingViewHolder">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried that not so long ago, edited it in with my quesiton, then re-edited back to my old XML file because this didn't work. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing setContentView() twice; so activity will take setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity1); Instead of doing this, take one relative layout as activity's setContenView and in that first add your gridView and after that add one linear or relative layout. By this way, both the views will come one above another. Then instantiate your drawing view and idd it's object to your upper view.

Comment: I changed my xml to how you explained and changed setContentView. I've added the xml (see EDIT) hoevever it still leaves me with the `GridView` on top.